# Difference Between Total Least Squares Plane and Plane Orthogonal to Principal Axis of Inertia Tensor

Tags: algorithms, physics, least-squares

Given a finite set $P$ of points in $\mathbb{E}^3$ , one can calculate an approximating plane either as the solution of a [Total Least Squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_least_squares) problem or by interpreting the problem physically, assigning a unit mass to each point and taking the best-approximating plane that contains the center of gravity and, that is orthogonal to one of the prinicipal axes of the [Inertia Tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia#Inertia_tensor).

as both of the above mentioned methods can be formulated on basis of squared coordinate differences, I don't see any criterion for preferring one over the other or even any argument in favor or against why both methods must yield identical planes.

> **Questions:**
>
> - do both methods yield identical planes?
> - if they need not be identical, what are bounds on the angle between their normals?
> - what are criteria for preferring one method over the other?

Comment: I expect I'm making an embarrassing mistake by saying this, but... don't both approaches just boil down to minimising $(X\beta - r)^T(X\beta - r)$ over $\beta\in S^2$? (writing $X$ for the $n\times 3$ matrix whose $i$th row is the transpose of your $i$th data point, and $r$ is an $n$-vector whose components are all the same real number).

Comment: @DCM the principal axes of the inertia tensor correspond to eigenvectors of a matrix and one question is whether that is also true for total least squares